# in javascript es6, How to call constructor method without using the class name?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, polymorphism, es6-class

I'm trying to create a parent class that can handle the basic CRUD function, but I can't figure out how to call constructor in static method.

```
class Model {
  static find(id) {
    var attrs = someDBcalls();
    var obj = new CurrentClass(attrs);   // how?
    return obj;
  }
}

class User extends Model {
  constructor(attrs){
    // initialize class.
  }
}

User.find(1);  // shall return an User object.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var obj = new this(attrs);` as demonstrated below:

```js
function someDBcalls(id) {
  return { id, success: true };
}

class Model {
  static find(id) {
    var attrs = someDBcalls(id);
    var obj = new this(attrs);
    return obj;
  }
}

class User extends Model {
  constructor(attrs) {
    super();
    // initialize class.
    console.log(attrs);
  }
}

var user = User.find(1);  // shall return an User object.
console.log(user instanceof User);
```